# Count over time elements that are greater than some value

Tags: prometheus

I have a metric that provides sample execution times, and I would like to count over time the number of those metric elements that surpassed some value.

I can easily count the total number metric elements:

```
count_over_time(sample_execution_time[1h])
```

but I cannot find a way to filter metric values in ranges (the following query is not accepted by prometheus):

```
count_over_time((sample_execution_time > .5)[1h])
```

I went over and over prometheus querying documentation but I cannot find any similar example. Any idea on how to filter metric values inside ranges?

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a workaround: by adding a recording rule with the condition I want, I'm then able to use it in a `count_over_time`.